# Can I set Direct Mode with CosmosDB Data API?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a project that uses CloudTableClient and query the cosmos db in this way:

```
 var table = cloudTableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
 var cosmosResult = await table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(GetTableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>(queryOptions), tableContinuationToken, GetTableRequestOptions(requestOptions), operationContext);
```

If I use CosmosClient, I can set the ConnetionMode

```
CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(connectionString,
new CosmosClientOptions
{
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway // ConnectionMode.Direct is the default
});
```

However, with CouldTableClient, seems I can't find an option to set this. Is it possible to use Direct Mode with CouldTableClient or I actually need to move everything to CosmosClient in order to do it.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a Cosmos DB account targeting Table API?

Comment: You can't use the Cosmos SDK to connect to a Table API account.